# InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class <unknown> when using Ripple

Tags: android, android-view, android-selector

Tried to use ripple effect.

ripple_selector.xml:

```
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="#ff00ff00" >

    <item android:drawable="@android:color/black"/>

</ripple>
```

using:

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"

    android:background="@drawable/ripple_selector">
    ...
</LinearLayout>
```

And have error:

```
01-16 13:54:15.299: E/AndroidRuntime(19048): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class <unknown>
```

Tried this:

```
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:color="?android:colorControlHighlight" >

   <item android:id="@android:id/mask">
   <color android:color="@android:color/white" />
   </item>

</ripple>
```

Same error.

Comment: What's your minSdk? Are you running this on a device with API 21?

Comment: minSdk = 8, running on Android 4.4. But i'm using App compat. Or even with it ripple available only on 5.0+?

Comment: Ripple is not back-ported (yet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ripple is not backported due of the performance of the pre-lollipop UI thread. You should create two different directories (`drawable-v21` and `layout-v21`) that contains stuff available up lollipop

Comment: So...how van i make this effect on pre-5.0 Andoird? I saw libs like this https://github.com/siriscac/RippleView, but there based on button. I need Ripple effect on LinearLayout.